# Can Wagtail work with Google Cloud/ Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, wagtail

I have a Google Spreadsheet which currently is 25,000 rows but it will grow to about 100,000 rows.

I would be VERY grateful to anyone to chime in with some thoughts on what I am trying to achieve is possible?

I'd like for my Google Spreadsheet to be able to be searchable in a Wagtail CMS (password protected) environment?

Ideally I am thinking that the data (the 100,000 rows) is stored on Google Cloud (Google App Engine) for speed and efficiency.

Does the above make sense?

Thank you for all help/ advice

Comment: I edited the answer adding the link to the github repo (I just realized I hadn't added it before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your data in some Storing solution integrated with App Engine such as [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-datastore), [Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql) or [CloudSQL for Postgres](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres). Once in there you can retrieve the data you need from your App.

There is actually a [github repo from the same creators than Wagtail library (Torchbox)](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-appengine-demo) with an example on Wagtail + GAE Flexible + Cloud SQL. I haven't tried it myself but something like this should work for your case.

Also if you want to serve your Spreadsheet as static data that can be downloadable, you can use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage)